# Windows Forms e Panels

Tags: c#, winforms

Como utilizo um único form para apresentar diversas telas, como por exemplo login, registro, administração, etc?

É possível utilizando o componente panel, porem a renderização do mesmo é lenta, além de ser desagradável desenvolver deste modo.

---

Posso estar falando asneira, mas imagino uma solução mais ou menos assim.

`frmPrincipal` = Contém a Windows Form com os componentes fixos.

`duvLogin` = Contém os componentes visuais que serão ativados na `frmPrincipal` quando solicitado.

`duvRegistro` = Contém os componentes visuais que serão ativados na `frmPrincipal` quando solicitado.

Gostaria de saber o modo correto ou mais adequado para se organizar as telas na form.

Comment: utilize a sugestão da Shura16

Answer (score 1):

O melhor então é usar a propriedade `IsMdiContainer` do form principal. Defina-a como `true`.

Nos outros forms (internos), você usa a propriedade `MdiParent` (definida em código antes do `show()`).

Assim você só tem uma tela principal e outras telas internas. Vou postar um link com tutorial detalhado para mais informações:

http://www.macoratti.net/09/08/c_mdi1.htm

---

Para o caso específico de tela de login, recomendo que use outro form, escondendo o primeiro, abrindo e exibindo o segundo e fechando o primeiro (nessa ordem). Para as outras use o caso citado acima.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o `UserControl` para construir os componente de login, registro e etc... e adicionar no form principal o controle correspondente.

Cria um `UC` login e outro registro e no form principal você adiciona um painel para carregar os `UCs`:

para o código a baixo imagine a seguinte situação:

**Form principal**:

1. `painel_principal`;

**Users Control**;

1. UC login;
2. UC Registro;

---

```
private UC_login uc_login=new UC_login ();
private UC_Registro uc_registro=new UC_Registro ();

public void TrocarUC(string controle)
{
   panel_principal.Controls.Clear();
   if(controle=="login")
   {
      panel_principal.Controls.Add(uc_login);
   }
   else if(controle=="registro")
   {
       panel_principal.Controls.Add(uc_registro);
   }
}
```